# How can i setup my php code to change my CSS background picture daily

Tags: php, html, css

I have a website that has a background, and i want it to change daily.

In my directory I have a background. each background has a number at the end.

```
././background1.jpg
```

In this case this file has a 1 tacked to it. So depending on the day the php will rewrite the css such that on a new day a new background will be set.

Comment: I imagine you could come up with an algorithm to generate an image number based on the day of the week, or the day of the year, the unix timestamp, etc. I suggest that you make an attempt, then show us what you tried and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either use the day of the week numbers, or day of the month numbers. Anything further than that you'll probably need a database or a save file or something. This is the simplest way:

```
//SHOW ONE IMAGE PER DAY OF THE WEEK FOR 7 IMAGES
$dotw = new \DateTime("NOW");
$dotwNum = $dotw->format('w');
echo "<body style='background: url(../../image{$dotwNum}.jpg)'></div>";

//SHOW ONE IMAGE PER DAY OF THE MONTH FOR 30 IMAGES
$dotm = new \DateTime("NOW");
$dotmNum = $dotw->format('j');
echo "<body style='background: url(../../image{$dotmNum}.jpg)'></div>";
```

Comment: thank you, Emylee! This is wonderfully implemented.